# Python log file

Tags: python

Hello guys what can be the problem?
also i printed the file name as binance_log.txt i am sure file in location
but i get AttributeError: 'Binance' object has no attribute 'log_file'

```
class Binance:

    def __init__(self, log_file, nominal_btc_price):
        self.nominal_btc_price = nominal_btc_price
        self.update_balances()
        self.log_file = log_file


    def log_print(self,string):
        print(string)
        self.log_file.write(f'{str(string)}\n')

    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_file = open('Binance_log.txt', 'w')
    x = Binance(log_file, nominal_btc_price=11800)

    print(x.get_total_balance("USDT"))
    print(x.get_total_balance("BTC"))

    asyncio.gather(
        x.sell_market('BTCUSDT', 0.00091, 15000)
    )

    log_file.close()
```

When i run i get following output.

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Binance_log.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1254'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Arbitraj\Binance.py", line 167, in <module>
    x = Binance(log_file)
  File "c:\Arbitraj\Binance.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.update_balances()
  File "c:\Arbitraj\Binance.py", line 32, in update_balances
    self.btc_total_balance = self.get_total_balance("BTC")
  File "c:\Arbitraj\Binance.py", line 107, in get_total_balance
    self.log_print(balance)
  File "c:\Arbitraj\Binance.py", line 27, in log_print
    self.log_file.write(f"{str(string)}\n")
AttributeError: 'Binance' object has no attribute 'log_file'
```

Comment: What is the `Binance` object? Why do you expect it to have a `log_file` attribute? Can you show the `__init__` method for it?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example to make us able to reproduce your problem. Currently it doesn't work because `Binance` is unknown. When, where and how is `log_print()` called? And by the way: What is the error? I see no error in your output. There is just a tranceback but now exception.

Comment: If `print(log_file)` worked, and showed your file object, then that object is obviously named `log_file` - not `self.log_file`.

Comment: all  codes in in Binance class

class Binance'

Comment: You're calling `self.update_balances()`, which eventually uses `self.log_file`, before the statement that initializes it. Flip the last two lines in your `__init__` function.